# How to identify unconnected siblings in a graph?

Tags: python, nodes, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, networkx

I have a directed acyclic graph as shown in the figure below.
[image: GRAPH WITH SIBLING NODES]

I want to identify all such group of nodes in this graph that satisfy following conditions:

- None of the nodes in a group are connected to each other
- Nodes in a group have exactly same set of parent and children nodes

For example, following group of nodes will be obtained from the above graph:

Group 1: {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}

Group 2: {16, 17}

Group 3: {19, 20}

Group 4: {21, 22}

I have thousands of such graphs (some with as large as 10k nodes). I'm looking for an efficient algorithm for doing this in Python using networkx.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that first request is redundant because second request covers it. It is not possible to have same set of parents and children for two connected nodes. For connected nodes, one node has other node in parent set and vice verse in children set.

So nodes in same group have same set of parent and children nodes. In python there is a simple solution implemented with dict indexing by pair of parent and children sets. I am not sure how efficient it is, but it is worth a try.

```
from collections import defaultdict
children = {
    1: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    2: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    3: [9, 10],
    4: [9, 10],
    5: [9, 10],
    6: [9, 10],
    7: [9, 10],
    8: [9, 10],
    9: [10],
    10: [11, 12, 13],
    11: [14, 15],
    12: [13, 14, 15],
    13: [16, 17],
    14: [16, 17],
    15: [16, 17],
    16: [18],
    17: [18],
    18: [19, 20],
    19: [21, 22],
    20: [21, 22],
    21: [],
    22: [],
}
# Collect parents
parents = defaultdict(list)
for a, bs in children.iteritems():
    for b in bs:
        parents[b].append(a)
# Use default dict to collect nodes that have same parents and children
store = defaultdict(list)
for node in children.iterkeys():
    store[(tuple(sorted(children[node])), tuple(sorted(parents[node])))].append(node)
# Result
for s in store.itervalues():
    if len(s) > 1:
        print s
```

From image, group {11, 12} is not a result. 11 is not connected to 13.

Comment: thanks ante. have fixed the wrong example result. will check how well this code scales up.

Comment: @Parashar If you are using networkx, I think methods for parents and children are predecessors() and  successors(). You can try with frozenset instead tuple, maybe it is faster for indexing. For that change tuple(sorted(nodes)) -> frozenset(nodes).

Comment: It works very well. Accepted your answer as solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ante has provided an elegant solution to my question.
I have modified his code a little to be used with networkx graphs in Python 3.5

Given a  directed acyclic graph `G`.

```
lineage = defaultdict(list)
for node in G.nodes():
    lineage[frozenset(G.predecessors(node)), frozenset(G.successors(node))].append(node)
for i in lineage.values():
    if len(i) > 1:
        print (i)  # a list containing the groups defined in the question
```

Thank you again Stack Overflow!